# How to send a mail via typo3 8 using smtp settings?

Tags: smtp, typo3, typo3-8.x

I have set the code below in LocalConfiguration.php

```html
'MAIL' => [
   'transport' => 'smtp',
   'transport_sendmail_command' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i',
   'transport_smtp_encrypt' => 'ssl',
   'transport_smtp_password' => 'xxxxx',
   'transport_smtp_server' => 'smtp.xxx.com.2525',
   'transport_smtp_username' => 'sample@gmail.com',
],
```

But i have not receiving any mails via testmail in install tool with these settings.

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Is your SMTP server configured to allow mails from your host? You should verify this outside of TYPO3 with tools like [smtp-cli](https://github.com/mludvig/smtp-cli) first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this configuration. This working fine for me.

```
'MAIL' => [
       'defaultMailFromName' => '0',
       'transport' => 'smtp',
       'transport_sendmail_command' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i ',
       'transport_smtp_encrypt' => 'ssl',
       'transport_smtp_password' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
       'transport_smtp_server' => 'smtp.gmail.com:465',
       'transport_smtp_username' => 'yoursmtpemail@gmail.com',
   ],
```

Make sure you have enabled SMTP in your mail service such as google.

Greetings!